# Upon logout i m still able to access the page (which is after login) without login required (by typing URL)

Tags: python, html, django

**Problem Description : -** When i login (i m redirected to the page required page) and after that when i logout and then type the URL of the page (present after login) i m still able to access the page (present after login without login required)

i tried deleting session, cookies, even `set_expiry()` and also i read the documentation that `logout()` does that but all in vain.

here's the code i tried:-

In views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('IP form'))
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Please provide valid credentials')
            return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)
        del request.set_session['username':username]
        del request.session['password':password]
        del request.delete_cookie['username': username]
        del request.delete_cookie['password':password]
    else:
        return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        logout(request)
        del request.session['username':username]
        del request.session['password':password]
        del request.delete_cookie['username': username]
        del request.delete_cookie['password':password]
        #auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))


@login_required
def form_name_view(request):                     #view after login
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('')
        response.delete_cookie('username')
        response.delete_cookie('password')
        del response.session['username']
        del response.session['password']
        return response
#        del request.session['username']
#        del request.session['password']

#        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CmdForm(request.POST)
```

settings.py

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 2
SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True
```

thnx to those willing to help.! :-)

Comment: well you seem to implement your own authentication system. Evidently Django uses `@login_required` for its own authentication system. Please do *not* use cookies/session variables to store passwords.

Comment: This is entirely a really bad idea. Use Django's auth framework.

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem thx for the reply. i have already tried using the Dango's auth framework (@login_required is mentioned in the code) but it doesn't clears the session cookies and i m able to access the **form_name_view** (Automation_page) when i login -->  logout and then if i type i URL of the (form_name_view)

Comment: @DanielRoseman thx for the reply. i have already tried using the Dango's auth framework (@login_required is mentioned in the code) but it doesn't clears the session cookies and i m able to access the form_name_view (Automation_page) when i login --> logout and then if i type i URL of the (form_name_view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured the answer to my problem.

Here's the changes i did to code

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('IP form'))
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Please provide valid credentials')
            return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)

    else:
        return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))


@login_required
def form_name_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        logout(request)
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('')
        return response
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CmdForm(request.POST)


   #here i just reverted back everything (from where i started)
```

Changes done:-

A) In cmd ran pip install django-session-timeout    (which said **requirement satisfied**)

B) In settings.py

added

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',  #<--added




SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 20
SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True      #<--- added 
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 25                     #<-- added
```

and bingo.! everything works just fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

You landed with login(), Logout users should use logout().
And there is no need to operate session.

Comment: can you please explain it with the help of code.! where in shall do the modifications.? thnku